# Issue with Double Quotes in java

Tags: java, csv, oracle10g, escaping, double-quotes

I am getting three types of value from the database when I am fetching value from a field.

All values are with double quotes. Those values are **`"Fitness Head`**, **`Fiteness " Head`** and **`Fitness Head"`**. I have to replace all double quotes with ***double*** double quotes using Java. What will be the java code to do that?

Thanks,
Somnath

Comment: could you first enlighten the **issue** you have with double quotes. Maybe you are looking to escape them in these values?

Comment: What could you be doing that requires doubling the double quotes? SQL handling? CSV generation?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to replace double quotes anywhere if you are using JDBC to insert/fetch the values - this is all taken care of as long as you use `PreparedStatement`s and placeholders.

[See this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

For example

```
String doubleQuotes = "\"Fitness head";
doubleQuotes.replace("\"", "\"\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing single double quotes with double double quotes:

```
"abc\"def".replace("\"", "\"\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

String newValue = oldValue.replace("\"", "\"\"");